# Return Type of UIViewController from Self

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to make an extension that returns a type of ViewController implicitly. For example:

```
extension UIViewController{
    @nonobjc func initiateAndAddToContainerReturnVc(identifier: String, storyboard: String, container: UIView) -> UIViewController{
        let view = initiateViewControllerFromName(identifier, storyboard: storyboard)
        addChildViewController(view)
        view.addToContainer(container: container)
        return view
    }
}
```

So that when I use it I can just do something like this:

```
var myViewController: MyViewController!
var container: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myViewController = MyViewController().initiateAndAddToContainerReturnVc(identifier: "myViewController", storyboard: "Main",container: container) as !MyViewController
}

func initiateViewControllerFromName(_ viewControllerName: String, storyboard: String) -> UIViewController {

    return UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerName)
}
```

What I'm asking is if I can change my extension to implicitly imply the ViewController is the MyViewController type of self rather than have to rely on "as! MyViewController"

I'm pretty sure I can do something with  but I've tried reading the documentation and searching this site but I still can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Whats is returning from `initiateViewControllerFromName(identifier, storyboard: storyboard)` ?

Comment: This extension adds a VC to a view container and then returns it as an initialised VC

Comment: sorry @PaulMarshal...understand what you're asking now. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// create a static method inside UIViewController extension

```
    extension UIViewController {
        static func initiateAndAddToContainerReturnVc(identifier: String, storyboard: String, container: UIView) -> Self {
            let view = initiateViewControllerFromName(identifier: identifier, storyboard: storyboard,viewcontrollerClass:self)
            addChildViewController(view)
            view.addToContainer(container: container)
            return view
        }
    }
```

// Define the initiateViewControllerFromName Method somewhere outside the extension and make it generic like below.

```
    class func initiateViewControllerFromName<T:UIViewController>(identifier:String, storyboard: String,viewcontrollerClass: T.Type) -> T {
       return UIViewController() as! T  // Add viewcontroller instance code here and typecast it to 'T'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try introducing a generic type parameter:

```
@nonobjc func initiateAndAddToContainerReturnVc<T: UIViewController>(identifier: String, storyboard: String, container: UIView) -> T{
    let view = initiateViewControllerFromName(identifier, storyboard: storyboard) as! T
    addChildViewController(view)
    view.addToContainer(container: container)
    return view
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
settings = MyViewController().initiateAndAddToContainerReturnVc(identifier: "myViewController",
                                                                storyboard: "Main",
                                                                container: container)
```

assuming that `settings` is of type `MyViewController`.

Comment: Apologies. settings should have been myViewController

Comment: afraid not no. Still gives me: "Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'MyViewController!'" and wants me to as! MyViewController

Comment: @LateNate Oops! You need to add `as! T` in the method, edited.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I caught that. But still same result. It wants me to explicitly use as! MyViewController when I call it. Frustrating. Just wanted a generic function to clean my code up a bit.

Comment: @LateNate could you post your  let view = initiateViewControllerFromName(identifier, storyboard: storyboard) method.